# crontab nohup trigger itself twice

Tags: linux, cron

This is the crontab:

```
0 10 * * * (file_path).sh > /data/log/(file_name).log 2>&1
```

Every day at 10am, this is the result when I check on this shell script using `ps -ef | grep 'file_name'`

```
report 1234 5678 0 10:00 ?    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c (file_path).sh > /data/log/(file_name).log 2>&1
report 8270 1234 0 10:00 ?    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c (file_path).sh > /data/log/(file_name).log 2>&1
report 9290 8270 0 10:00 ?    00:00:00 sqlplus -s @/(file_path).sql > /data/log/(file_name).sql.log 2>&1
```

Because of this, this crontab takes a very long time because it is running the shell script twice before going to the sql script.

When checking at `crontab -e`, there's only one line executing this. So there is no duplicate cronjobs running at the same time. Based on this one line, it is executing the shell script twice.

Anyone know why this keeps happening?

Answer (score 0):

Also note the using `(` `)` interpreted by the shell as creation of subshell.

Suggesting to remove  `(` `)`  from filename.

From your `ps` output:

```
report 1234 5678 0 10:00 ?    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c (file_path).sh > /data/log/(file_name).log 2>&1
report 8270 1234 0 10:00 ?    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c (file_path).sh > /data/log/(file_name).log 2>&1
report 9290 8270 0 10:00 ?    00:00:00 sqlplus -s @/(file_path).sql > /data/log/(file_name).sql.log 2>&1
```

It is possible to trace the process forking/spawning tree:

1234 spawns 8270 spawns 9290.

There could be some parallelism mechanism in your `(file_path).sh`